# Unable to download a file from the link, used CURL

Tags: web, curl

I am trying to download stockmarket data from NSE website, till 2018 i was able to get the file downloaded using CURL in command Line, But now its not working anymore.

Please help me a way to download it from command line.

**Working** : Using Chrome and clicking on the link

**Not Working** : CURL method, copying the link to chrome in another tab is also not working

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2019/JAN/cm01JAN2019bhav.csv.zip
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;nseindia&#46;com&#47;content&#47;historical&#47;EQUITIES&#47;2019&#47;JAN&#47;cm01JAN2019bhav&#46;csv&#46;zip" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;93fa56b8&#46;1546394430&#46;40ca86c6
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

A zip file has to be downloaded without being corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

What's the Referer Page? -- The page you can do this download manually.
Try add `-e` Referer URL,
And change your UA.

But apparently the site don't like someone to leech their data anymore, so you might need to stop this.

Comment: Tried adding referer and changing UA. But it is not working as you said